# BeautifulSoup Web Scraping into Dataframe

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect all of the terms found on these websites: https://www.emdat.be/Glossary, https://www.fema.gov/about/glossary, https://hazards.fema.gov/nri/natural-hazards, https://training.fema.gov/programs/emischool/el361toolkit/glossary.htm. I get this far with my code but my output dataframe shows the terms in each row but the definitions are the columns (not aligned with the words per row). My code right now using one website as an example is:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.emdat.be/Glossary"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = {}
for dd in soup.select("dd"):
    dt = dd.find_previous("dt")
    data.setdefault(dt.text, {}).update(
        {
            dd.p.text.strip("id="): dd.p.find_next_sibling(
                text=True
            ).strip()
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
print(df.head().to_markdown())
``
```

Comment: What's wrong for the first site?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.emdat.be/Glossary'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

data = []
for dd in soup.select('dd'):
    dt = dd.find_previous('dt'):
    data.append((dt.text.strip(), dd.text.strip()))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Word', 'Definition'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                     Word                                         Definition
0                Affected  People requiring immediate assistance during a...
1                Airburst  An explosion of a comet or meteoroid within th...
2         Animal accident  Human encounters with dangerous or exotic anim...
3                Ash Fall  Fine (less than 4 mm in diameter) unconsolidat...
4               Avalanche  A large mass of loosened earth material, snow,...
..                    ...                                                ...
94      Volcanic activity  A type of volcanic event near an opening/vent ...
95          Vulnerability  Degree of loss (from 0% to 100%) resulting fro...
96               Wildfire  Any uncontrolled and non-prescribed combustion...
97                   Wind  Diﬀerences in air pressure resulting in the ho...
98  Winter storm/Blizzard  A low pressure system in winter months with si...

[99 rows x 2 columns]
```